# how to stop jenkins that is running in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I started jenkins in docker with command like this:

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart always jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

trying to stop it with command
docker kill 
gets response
Cannot kill container: : permission denied

Also trying to stop container also gets permission denied.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this happen only with Jenkins, or for every other container as well?

Comment: yes, running on kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove jenkins from docker by uninstalling docker from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

run command in ubuntu `sudo docker stop {id container}`
or
you can stop container in docker desktop